# About the meaning of glInvalidateFramebuffer

Tags: opengl-es

I have a question about the general use of glInvalidateFramebuffer:

As far as I know, the purpose of glInvalidateFramebuffer is to "skip the store of framebuffer contents that are no longer needed". Its main purpose on tile based gpus is to get rid of depth and stencil contents if only color is needed after rendering. I do not understand why this is necessary. As far as I know if I render to an FBO then all of this data is stored in that FBO. Now if I do something with only the color contents or nothing with that FBO in a subsequent draw, why is the depth/stencil data accessed at all? It is supposedly stored somewhere and that eats bandwidth, but as far as I can tell it is already in FBOs GPU memory as the result of the render so when does that supposed expensive additional store operation happen?

There are supposedly expensive preservaton steps for FBO attachments but why are those necessary if the data is already in Gpu memory as result of the render?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Framebuffers in a tile-based GPU exist in two places - the version stored in main memory (which is persistent), and the working copy inside the GPU tile buffer (which only exists for the duration of that tile's fragment shading). The content of the tile buffer is written back to the buffer in main memory at the end of shading for each tile.

The objective of tile-based shading is to keep as much of the state inside that tile buffer, and avoid writing it back to main memory if it's not needed. This is important because main memory DRAM accesses are phenomenally power hungry. Invalidation at the end of each render pass tells the graphics stack that those buffers don't need to be persisted, so means the write back from tile buffer to main memory can be avoided.

I've written a longer article on it here if you want more detail:

https://developer.arm.com/solutions/graphics/developer-guides/understanding-render-passes/single-view

For non-tile-based GPUs the main use case seems to be using it as a lower cost version of a `clear` at the start of a render pass if you don't actually care about the starting color. It's likely there is little benefit to using it at the end of the render pass (but it should not hurt either).

Comment: When you say "main memory" do you  mean CPU side memory? Or GPU side memory? Or is the GPU tile buffer in a special memory area?

Comment: "Main memory" it could be either. For most mobile and laptop GPUs there is no separation between CPU and GPU memory - it's all just system RAM.

Comment: "GPU tile buffer" is a special small on-chip memory inside the GPU. It's not accessible from outside of the GPU; it's a fixed function dedicated scratch buffer.

Comment: Oh. Is that the buffer that makes framebuffer fetches from fragment shader fast? Ok, so the point is to reduce transfers between that buffer and main gpu memory, right? Is there a GLES document that specifies the role of glInvalidateFramebuffer with regard to that tile buffer?

Comment: "Is there a GLES document ...?" No - the API specification doesn't specify any particular micro-architecture implementation. The presence of a tile-buffer is purely implementation detail, and does not alter the API behavior.

Comment: And what is the role of glInvalidateFramebuffer on platforms that are not tile based? Like desktop AMD and NVidia?